# Using ninject (DI) to instantiate a presenter with webforms and MVP

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, inversion-of-control, ninject

I've got a webforms app that I'd like to use dependency injection on. I realize that I can't use DI to construct the each Page because webforms doesn't have the proper hooks like aspnet MVC does.

Nate Kohari suggests on the [ninject mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/317fc48387399aa6) that you could create a base page that would handle dependency resolution via property injection, which certainly seems like it would work.

But my webforms app implements the Model-View-Presenter pattern and I want to know why I couldn't just use my container to resolve my Presenter in the view's constructor since my presenter should have all the dependencies that I would need to resolve? Is there any dependency that I would want/need to resolve that sits directly on the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the link, I see no functional difference between what he/she is suggesting and the alternative you mention in your last paragraph.  Having the kernel property in the base page seems overengineered, since you are just going to be accessing a static kernel at some point anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm glad there is someone that agrees with me. Thanks Phil!